# ASP.NET - Template Field Drop Down List

Tags: asp.net

Please see the code below:

```
Protected Sub GVHistoricNames_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GVHistoricNames.RowUpdating
            Try
                'Dim strUsercode As String = GVHistoricNames.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text
                Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(GVHistoricNames.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddlUsercode"), DropDownList)
                MsgBox(ddl.SelectedIndex)


            Catch ex As Exception
                 'I don't swallow exceptions
            Finally

            End Try
        End Sub
```

I am trying to get the selected value of a drop down list.  The template field is defined like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Usercode">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUsercode" runat="server" SelectedValue ='<%# Bind("Usercode") %>' DataTextField="Usercode" DataValueField="Usercode">
                </asp:DropDownList> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

MsgBox(ddl.SelectedIndex) always prints an empty String in: GVHistoricNames_RowUpdatinGVHistoricNames_RowUpdating.  What am I doing worng?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are not binding or populating your dropdown list some where in the page life cycle before the rowUpdating event. Make sure you use `not isPostback` as appropriate. Check the syntax  there as I'm a C# guy!